# why net::ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT in chrome when redirecting to 'data:' links?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, google-chrome-extension

I developing new extension for google chrome browser, and now I stacked this task:

1. Use chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest to intercept the request.
2. Prevent the request from executing (but not completing its error) by redirecting to a link like `data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8`, (empty js).

developer chrome docs says, that I can do it like this:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener((details)=>{
    //some if statments and etc...

    return { redirectUrl: 'data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8,'}

}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["blocking"]);
```

And I am very sure it's allowed to redirect to `data:` links like this, because of this docs:

> **redirectUrl**
> Only used as a response to the onBeforeRequest and onHeadersReceived events. If set, the original request is prevented from being sent/completed and is instead redirected to the given URL. Redirections to non-HTTP schemes such as data: are allowed. Redirects initiated by a redirect action use the original request method for the redirect, with one exception: If the redirect is initiated at the onHeadersReceived stage, then the redirect will be issued using the GET method. Redirects from URLs with ws:// and wss:// schemes are ignored.

[from this documentations](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#type-BlockingResponse)

But when I tries to do this, I see this error in console: `net:ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT`

So, what is my problem?

P.S. in my **mainfest.json** I have this `permisions`:

```json
"permissions": [ "webNavigation", "tabs", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>", "notifications", "storage", "contextMenus", "unlimitedStorage" ],
```

Comment: Use `'data:text/plain,'` which does the same without a warning, see https://crbug.com/949070

Comment: No, I tried this just now, and result is absolutly same

Comment: I guess you didn't reload the extension after editing it.

Comment: absolutly not. I reloaded extension, and also I tried base64 image data and `about:blank`. And also I tried Opera browser and got absolultly same error

Comment: It definitely works for me, so another guess would be it's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: maybe this can help: I tested, and as I can see, images like `data:image/png;base64,` loads succesfull problem only with scripts in fact. And also maybe this can be useful: i forgot to provide my secure policy from mainfest.json. here it is:
`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self';"`

Comment: Still works properly here on scripts and with the csp added.